# Присваивание значения необязательному аргументу функции

Tags: javascript, функции

У меня есть код с функцией, выглядящий как-то так:

```js
function sum(a,b=3,c=1){
return a + b + c;
}
```

Можно ли выполнить функцию задав значение переменной *c* пропустив *b*?
Так не работает:

```js
sum(1,c = 5);
//Должен возвращать 9(1+3+5)
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Можно так: `function sum({a,b=3,c=1}){  return a + b + c; }; sum({a : 1, c : 5})`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(1, undefined, 5);
```

вернёт 9.

Других "красивых" путей по моему - нет.